# How to link Google Assistant with my app to get Assistant response?

Tags: android, xamarin, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I already have an app(developed in XAMARIN) that control gate open and close using message sent to the device attached with the door.Now i want those thing done through Google Assistant.I have already followed DialogFlow and Integrate Action on Google.But unable to call my app method that is already define to open gate.Is there any callback method to get Google Assistant response?And how to integrate those callback?

Comment: Which platform is your app for? Android Things? A mobile phone?

Comment: Mobile Phone @NickFelker

Comment: Are you using the normal Google Assistant, or using the Google Assistant SDK witihin your app?

Comment: @NickFelker normal google assistant.

Comment: The best integration right now would be sending a push notification from your action webhook. You may also want to look at app actions: https://developer.android.com/guide/actions/

Comment: I am using this code :
app.intent('setup_push', (conv) => {
  conv.ask(new UpdatePermission({intent: 'tell_latest_tip'}));
});
but UpdatePermission is not defined warning is shown.any suggestion?

Comment: This would be more of a push notiication for your app, not through the Assistant

Comment: @NickFelker  Please explain once.

Comment: You want your action to control your app. You can look into app actions. A second way to do it is, from you webhook, to send a push notification to your app.